# solution of an implicit equation with fzero on MATLAB

Tags: implicit, equation, matlab

I've been trying to solve this implicit equation by using `fzero` in MATLAB. File that holds the code is named as `"colebrook"` and I've typed so far is as below.

```
D = input('Please enter the pipe diameter in meters: ');
V = input('Please enter the fluid velocity in m/s: ');
rho = input('Please enter fluid density in kg/m^3: ');
mew = input('Please enter fluid viscosity in kg/m*s: ');
Re = D*V*rho/mew;

eps = input('Enter absolute roughness in milimeters: ');
eD = eps/(D*1000);

a = fzero(colebrookfunc,0.1);
fprintf(a);
```

Equation that I want to solve is kept in another m-file called `"colebrookfunc"`, and the code it contains is as below.

```
function F = colebrookfunc(x)
    F = x - 1./(-4 * log10(eD/3.7 + 1.256./(Re*x.^0.5))).^2;
```

When i run in i get this error(s):

```
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

Error in ==> colebrookfunc at 2
F = x - 1./(-4 * log10(eD/3.7 + 1.256./(Re*x.^0.5))).^2;
Error in ==> colebrook at 28
a = fzero(colebrookfunc,0.1);
```

What is my mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `colebrookfunc` as a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html). Also, unless you define `colebrookfunc` as a nested function (which you, apparently, don't), you need to somehow pass the parameters to the function.

Thus, your call to `fzero` should look like:

```
a = fzero(@(x)colebrookfunc(x,eD,Re),0.1)
```

And the first line of `coolebrookfunc` has to be

```
function F = colebrookfunc(x,eD,Re)
```