# solving colebrook (nonlinear) equation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-functions

I want to do in python [what this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688510/solution-of-an-implicit-equation-with-fzero-on-matlab) in MATLAB.

I have installed anaconda, so i have numpy and sympy libraries. So far I have tried with numpy nsolve, but that doesn't work. I should say I'm new with python, and also that I konw how to do it in MATLAB :P.

[The equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2*log%28%282.51/%28331428*sqrt%28x%29%29%29%2b%280.0002/%283.71*0.26%29%29%29=1/sqrt%28x%29):

`-2*log(( 2.51/(331428*sqrt(x)) ) + ( 0.0002 /(3.71*0.26)) ) = 1/sqrt(x)`

Normally, I would solve this iteratively, simply guessing x on the left and than solving for the x on the right. Put solution on the left, solve again. Repeat until left x is close to right. I have an idea what solution should be.

So I could do that, but that's not very cool. I want to do it numerically.
My 15€ Casio calculator can solve it as is, so I think it shouldn't be to complicated?

Thank you for your help,

edit: so I have tried the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq

w=10;
d=0.22;
rho=1.18;
ni=18.2e-6;

Re=(w*d*rho)/ni
k=0.2e-3;
d=0.26;

def f(x,Re,k,d):
    return (
        -2*log((2.51/(Re*sqrt(x)))+(k/(3.71*d)),10)*sqrt(x)+1
            );

print(
    scipy.optimize.brentq
        (
        f,0.0,1.0,xtol=4.44e-12,maxiter=100,args=(),full_output=True,disp=True
        )
    );
```

And i get this result:

```
    r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
TypeError: f() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Is it because I'm solving also solving for constants?

edit2:
so I think I have to assign constants via args=() keyword, so I changed:

```
f,0.0,1.0,xtol=4.44e-12,maxiter=100,args=(Re,k,d),full_output=True,disp=True
```

but now I get this:

```
-2*log((2.51/(Re*sqrt(x)))+(k/(3.71*d)),10)*sqrt(x)+1
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Anyway, when I put in a different equation; lets say `2*x*Re+(k*d)/(x+5)` it works, so I guess I have to transform the equation.

so it dies here: log(x,10)..

edit4: correct syntax is log10(x)... Now it works but I get zero as a result

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. I've done a few things here.  First, I've used a simpler definition of the function using the global variables you've defined anyway. I find this a little nicer than passing the args= to the solvers, it also enables easier use of your own custom solvers if you ever need something like that. I've used the generic `root` function as an entry point rather than using a particular algorithm - this is nice because you can simply pass a different method later. I've also fixed up your spacing to be as recommended by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and fixed your erronious rewriting of the equation. I find it more intuitive simply to write LHS - RHS rather than manipulate as you did. Also, notice that I've replaced all the integer literals with 1.0 or whatever to avoid problems with integer division. 0.02 is regarded as a pretty standard starting point for the friction factor.

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import root

w = 10.0
d = 0.22
rho = 1.18
ni = 18.2e-6

Re = w*d*rho/ni
k = 0.2e-3

def f(x):
    return (-2*numpy.log10((2.51/(Re*numpy.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.71*d))) - 1.0/numpy.sqrt(x))

print root(f, 0.02)
```

I must also mention that fixed point iteration is actually faster than even Newton's method for this problem. You can use the built-in fixed point iteration routine by defining `f2` as follows:

```
def f2(x):
    LHS = -2*numpy.log10((2.51/(Re*numpy.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.71*d)))
    return 1/LHS**2
```

Timings (starting further from the root to show speed of convergence):

```
%timeit root(f, 0.2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 428 µs per loop

%timeit fixed_point(f2, 0.2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop
```

Comment: Hello chthonicdeamon, and thank you for your input. I have some questions. 1.Can you please elaborate this "I've used the generic root function as an entry point rather than using a particular algorithm - this is nice because you can simply pass a different method later." 2. Yes, thank you, my equation was dumb. 3. So if I understand correctly, fixed-point method is pretty much what I would do manually, like I said in the first post?  4. I will edit if I have more. You have been a great help. Thank you

Comment: 1. If you look at [the documentation for scipy.optimize.root](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html), you will see that the various algorithms are selectable from a parameter, rather than having to change the actual function name. 3. Pretty much, but the function wraps the convergence procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are a little off: you're tagging it as `sympy` which is a library for *symbolic* computations, but say that you want to solve it numerically. In case the latter is your actual intention, here are relevant scipy docs:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding

Comment: thank you, I have chosen brentq, I will test it later. Tnx again

Answer (score 0):

Scipy with `fixed_point` is to be preferred also because the `root` does not converge for guess values far away, like the 0.2 in the @chthonicdaemon %timeit exempla.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use comments sections for comments.

Comment: @blondelg, I would have, if I only had enough reputation.

Comment: good point. That said, linking actions to reputation is made to improve behaviour. Bypassing rules wont definitively increase your reputation whereas respecting rules to ask and answer questions right, will increase your rep points.

Answer (score 0):

The solver solutions from numpy in the answer above are rather slow for this problem. A normal halving method here would be about 5 times faster and as accurate as the root and fixed_point methods. The code below has the simple halving method in the factor() function. Both the factor() function and the fixed_point method are timed.

```
import numpy
import time

from scipy.optimize import fixed_point

w = 10.0
d = 0.5
rho = 1.18
ni = 18.2e-6

Re = w*d*rho/ni
k = 0.2e-3

def f2(x):
    LHS = -2*numpy.log10((2.51/(Re*numpy.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.71*d)))
    return 1/LHS**2

def f(x):
    return (-2*numpy.log10((2.51/(Re*numpy.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.71*d))) - 1.0/numpy.sqrt(x))

def factor():
    min_value = 0.001
    max_value = 0.2
    tolerance = 0.000001
    iterations = 0
    max_iterations = 100

    while iterations < max_iterations:
        factor = (min_value + max_value) / 2
        result = f(factor)
        if abs(result) > tolerance:
            iterations += 1
            if result < 0:
                min_value = factor
            else:
                max_value = factor
        else:
            return factor
    return 0

tic = time.perf_counter()
a = factor()
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"*** Solution reached in {toc - tic:0.6f} seconds")
print(f"Factor found: {a}") 

tic = time.perf_counter()
a = fixed_point(f2, 0.2)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"*** Solution reached in {toc - tic:0.6f} seconds")
print(f"Factor found: {a}")
```

> *** Solution reached in 0.000098 seconds
> Factor found: 0.01750585120916367
> *** Solution reached in 0.000429 seconds
> Factor found: 0.017505852375130332