# fixed point iteration over list (colebrook)

Tags: python, scipy, iteration, physics

I need to calculate the friction factor using the Colebrook-Equation, but unlike most cases it needs to be over a length, so the Reynolds number is a list, not a float.

I basically used what this guy [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880134/solving-colebrook-nonlinear-equation-in-python) recommended (fixed point iteration), specially because it will be part of a bigger programm which wasn't very fast when I did it in Matlab.

For my interpretation of that code I oriented myself at the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fixed_point.html) of the fixed_point documentation, because there they also pass arguments in form of lists into the function (or actually the solver). *v* is a list with 1000 elements.

```
k = 0.000045
d = 0.03
reynolds = d/10**(-6)*v

def f(x, Re):
    LHS = -2*np.log10((2.51/(Re*np.sqrt(x))) + (k/(3.71*d)))
    return 1/LHS**2 

x0 = [0.02]*1000

Re = np.array(reynolds)
result = fixed_point(f,x0, args = Re)

print(result)
```

I made sure that the starting value and the Reynolds-argument have the same length and I still get an error message.

```
File " ... ", line 72, in <module>
result = fixed_point(f,x0, args = Re)

...

TypeError: f() takes 2 positional arguments but 1001 were given
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamentally here although I'm sitting on it longer than this problem should be taking me.
Thanks for you help,

Comment: What about `result = fixed_point(f,x0, args=[reynolds])` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think that was it! I have to check if the results are valid but at the very least I now get a numpy array with 1000 elements  and no error